# Automate the Boring Stuff Chapter 6 : Password Locker

Tags: python

```
#! python3
#pw.py - An insecure password locker program.
PASSWORDS = {'email' : 'JKL:DF234@#$',
             'twitter' : 'asd;lfjk@#$',
             'youtube' : 'as;ldkjf;sljf234'}

import sys, pyperclip

if len(sys.argv) <2:
    print('Usage: python pw.py [account] - copy account password')
    sys.exit()

account = sys.argv[1] #first command line arg is the account name

if account in PASSWORDS:
    pyperclip.copy(PASSWORDS[account])
    print('Password ' + account + ' copied to clipboard.')
else:
    print('There is no account named ' + account)

@py.exe C:\Users\Path\To\File %*
@pause
```

I'm new to python and trying to figure out why this isn't working. I keep getting a syntax error at my @py.exe section and I'm not sure why. Any help would be appreciated.

```
"C:\Users\rowla\PycharmProjects\Password Locker\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:\Users\rowla\PycharmProjects\Password Locker\Password Locker.py"
  File "C:\Users\rowla\PycharmProjects\Password Locker\Password Locker.py", Line 22
    @py.exe C:\Users\rowla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\PythonScripts %*
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Can u show your error log?

Comment: It is not a valid Python statement. Looks like `@py.exe C:\Users\Path\To\File %*` and `@pause` should belong to the command line

Comment: Added the error to the main question. Thank you for your assistance. This has confused me as I went straight from the chapter in Automate the boring stuff, so I'm lost at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following part does not belong to your python program:

```
@py.exe C:\Users\Path\To\File %*
@pause
```

Create a .bat batch file with the above, then add the file to the system path on
Windows so that you can run it from the Run dialog.

Comment: Oh okay. Thank you! I'll try it when I get home.

Answer (score 1):

Like the comment by @Andreas says, `@py.exe ...` is not valid Python. You should have some python module like `pw.py` with the contents

```
#! python3
#pw.py - An insecure password locker program.
PASSWORDS = {'email' : 'JKL:DF234@#$',
             'twitter' : 'asd;lfjk@#$',
             'youtube' : 'as;ldkjf;sljf234'}

import sys, pyperclip

if len(sys.argv) <2:
    print('Usage: python pw.py [account] - copy account password')
    sys.exit()

account = sys.argv[1] #first command line arg is the account name

if account in PASSWORDS:
    pyperclip.copy(PASSWORDS[account])
    print('Password ' + account + ' copied to clipboard.')
else:
    print('There is no account named ' + account)
```

And then from the command line, you could run

```
py.exe C:\Users\path\to\pw.py email
py.exe C:\Users\path\to\pw.py not_in_locker
```

If you installed Python such that it is on your PATH (i.e. `python --version` does not raise some error), then you could instead call

```
python C:\Users\path\to\pw.py email
```